# In\On the 59th minute?

Tags: prepositions, time-reference

From Longman Phrasal Verbs Dictionary (surprisingly poorly edited, BTW): ***In the 59th minute*** Van Den Hornet conjured up a magnificent goal that brought his team to victory. Had I not already read that phrase I would have put its beginning as ***On the 59th minute*** by analogy with ***on the 4th of July***, for example. Which is correct? Various dictionaries I've tried to refer to regarding this issue proved to be of little help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *on* rather than *in* is actually more the exception than the rule. We use ***in*** to mean "inside of" or "within the confines of" when referring to minutes, months, years and centuries:

- He scored **in** the twelfth minute of overtime.
- She plans to visit Paris **in** March.
- My son was born **in** 2005.
- The Mona Lisa was painted **in** the 16th century.

Although we do use ***on*** when referring to specific days:

- We will drive to Houston **on** Saturday.
- My daughter's birthday is **on** the 19th.
- Cinco de Mayo falls **on** a Friday this year.
- **On** the first day of Christmas, my true love gave to me...

Answer (score 1):

"In the 59th minute" is a metaphor "[impossibly] before time expires" similar to "at the last moment" or "just in time" (also, "just in the nick of time").

Regrettably, some English speakers will use the construction, "on the 59th minute," despite this being wrong.  It likely comes from the idea of "on the stroke of midnight," referring to when a chime sounds or the old cowboy/gun slinger phrase, "at high noon" which comingles the idea of location with an infintely precise moment you cannot live "within."

The idea of "in a minute" likely comes from the idea of the smallest increment of time that is practical to "pass through."  while scientifically we measure time much more precisely than in single seconds, when it comes to living our lives, we generally do not.  Thus, we can say, "at the last second" in the sense of a location or the smallest measureable moment in time.  Philisophically speaking, things don't happen in our lives "inside" of a second.  But since minutes are made up of seconds, things do happen "inside" of a minute.  Thus, "in the 59th minute" is the correct way to express the idea.

Comment: _**At**_ for things that are simultaneous.  _**In**_ for things that are not - even if they are less than a second.  "_**In** the half second before the van hit me, my whole life flashed before my eyes.  **At** the precise moment  we collided, I threw up."_  (rough day)

Comment: I did wonder about 59th minute being used metaphorically when I read the question title, but I think from the context, without knowing which sport we're talking about exactly, I think it's more likely it's used literally here, referring to soccer. Goals in soccer are typically described as happening in X minute of the game, and since games are 90+ minutes long, a goal in the 59th wouldn't actually be "at the last moment."

Comment: @cjl750, I have to admit, I didn't consider that there might be a literal context.  Although, I would wonder if it wouldn't be very rare for someone to refer to an action taking place "on the 59th minute" of a 90 minute game.  But that's my perspective from American English, where I've never heard such a reference before.

Comment: No, I think you're right that it's still *in* the 59th, minute, not *on*, whether it's literal or figurative. Just saying that I think in this particular example the reference is probably actually literal.

Comment: FWIW, the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+11th+hour%2Cat+the+11th+hour%2F10%2Cat+the+59th+minute%2Cin+the+eleventh+hour%2Cat+the+eleventh+hour&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows instances of "at the 11th hour" and "in the 11th hour" but no instances of "in the 59th minute" or "at the 59th minute." I think that, in this case, it's meant to be a literal time.

Comment: The part of this sentence that I think is a little confusing is that it certainly gives me the impression that the goal was scored right at the end, but that wouldn't be the case for a soccer goal in the 59th minute. But then it occurred to me that another sport with "goals" (as opposed to "points" or "baskets" or "runs" or whatever) is hockey, which has three 20-minute periods. In that case, a goal in the 59th minute could be figuratively "just in time" and also literally in the 59th minute of the game!

Comment: "In the 59th" would mean at some point between 58.00...1 and 59.00...0; "on the 59th" would mean at the exact point of 59.00...0; I have used both when describing actions in a game.